# how can I set a timeout to a block in a test (junit)?

Tags: java, junit, timer, timeout, stopwatch

I want to limit a certain block in a test to 1 second.

I have tried this:

```
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new TimeoutException("test time: expected:"+expectedTimeMilli);
        }
    } ;
    new Timer().schedule(timerTask, 1L);
```

but the complier asks to wrap the `run()` body with try-catch.

I want to throw this exception to be caught in `main()` methd
(and return result code 3)

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than throwing TimeoutException, have it throw your own Exception that extends RuntimeException.

Note that this will kill your timer thread. If this is an issue, use ScheduledExecutorService